# About multi-module maven remote deployment fails

Tags: maven-plugin

I have a problem when I execute 'tomcat7-maven-plugin'

- pom.xml (packaging pom, has two modules)
- service

  - pom.xml (packaging jar)
- web2

  - pom.xml (packaging war, depends on service)

parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>DeployTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>DeployTest</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>web2</module>
        <module>service</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <finalName>DeployTest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

child-service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>DeployTest</artifactId>
        <groupId>DeployTest</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <groupId>service</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</project>
```

children-web:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>DeployTest</artifactId>
        <groupId>DeployTest</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>web2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>web2 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>service</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>web2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://192.168.1.109:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                    <server>tomcat</server>
                    <path>/DeployTest</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run the 'tomcat7:redeploy',throws exceptions:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project web2: Could not resolve dependencies for project DeployTest:web2:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find service:service:jar:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project web2: Could not resolve dependencies for project DeployTest:web2:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find service:service:jar:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project DeployTest:web2:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find service:service:jar:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
    ... 32 more
```

Please help me...
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I found a way.

Remove the following code from web pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <finalName>DeployTest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Add the following code in parent pom.xml `<build>` node:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy_install</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://192.168.1.109:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                    <path>/DeployTest</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your child-service pom.xml, remove the line `<groupId>service</groupId>`

In your child-web pom.xml, reference the service project with :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem still exists.....changes..Failure to find DeployTest:service:jar:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,

Comment: remove `<version>1.0</version>` from service pom.xml as well ... and add `<packaging>jar</packaging>` there

Comment: I don't understand your last question ... you are referencing service module in your web pom.xml ... but there are some errors in your service pom.xml that you have to correct, that's all ...

Comment: I packed into the 'war' is normal, just execute this command fails....I'll try....thank you very much

Comment: your service 'jar' will go in the web 'war' .. no problem with that ;-)